# Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value Rails 3 UTF8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, utf-8, percona

I've got an app which deals with a lot of data in other languages (webpage titles and meta descriptions). I recently switched from MySQL to Percona and have found all the errors which MySQL seemed to have silently errored on.

The only one I haven't managed to fix is

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value:
```

I've looked at the current questions and answers but they all assume a known encoding to convert to UTF8, I don't know the encoding.

What I'd like to do is get rails to convert it to UTF8 (I've tried force_encoding but that didn't work) or I'd like to check if it's UTF8 and if not get rid of it.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem when trying to insert unicode emoji into a mysql database... You might think you are safe with utf8, you're not. Emoji uses 4 bytes, and utf8 only uses 3 bytes. The solution is to use utf8mb4 encoding and collation.

You can do this by first updateing your database.yml too look like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my_database
  username: a_user
  password: the_password
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

If you have an existing database, you need to run this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE `[table]` 
  CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
MODIFY [column] VARCHAR(250)
    CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

If your haven't released to production yet, you can just do

```
bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

[Shamelessly taken from Jason Seifer](http://jasonseifer.com/2014/06/20/rails-4-mysql-and-emoji-mysql2error-incorrect-string-value-error)

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered this issue recently. It's essentially mysql default collation type is not utf8_unicode_ci.

Do the following. Backup your data if you have to.
I had to drop the database and recreate it

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
```

Change mysql database collation to utf8_unicode_ci ( phpMyAdmin might come in handy here)
Finally, restore your migration.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Enjoy.