# Mysql - Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value:

Tags: mysql

So I built a scraper and am pulling in some objects. The issue is some are foreign languages and it is tripping the mysql db up a bit. This is the error I got. Any idea what I can do with this? Thanks!

> Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: '\xC5\x8Dga, ...' for column
>   'description' at row 1: INSERT INTO `sammiches` (`country`,
>   `created_at`, `description`, `image`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES
>   ('Japan', '2013-05-03 01:17:06', 'A hot dog bun stuffed with fried
>   noodles, frequently topped with pickles, such as beni shōga, with
>   mayonnaise', '/wiki/File:Yakisoba_sandwich_by_kaex0r.jpg',
>   'Yakisoba-pan', '2013-05-03

Comment: Use UTF-8 in the database?

Answer (score 17):

This can also be triggered if the string you're trying to insert has invalid UTF-8 byte sequences. For example, in ruby you can remove any invalid characters using

```
string_with_invalid_sequences.encode('utf-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

[String#scrub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scrub) can be used in ruby 2.1 onwards

```
string_with_invalid_sequences.scrub
```

Comment: I don't know why, but you first suggestion helped me and scrub doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @across - does this work for you: `string_with_invalid_sequences.scrub('')`?

Comment: string_with_invalid_sequences.encode only this works for me..., none of the above solutions worked, scrub didn't work as well.

Comment: @ user1735921 still not working? did you check your ruby version?

Answer (score 10):

Probably your table is set to a non Utf8 CHARACTER SET. You can change this with this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_database_name`.`your_table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: Inside of a migration use: `ModelName.connection.execute('ALTER TABLE model_names CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8')`

Comment: @TomRossi it could be because it is outside the multilingual plane (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-16)

Answer (score 5):

You can find the answer here. I am not sure how to report duplicate.
[Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value Rails 3 UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039918/mysql2error-incorrect-string-value-rails-3-utf8/16934574#16934574)

For your convenience, let me reiterate my answer

---

I had encountered this issue recently. It's essentially mysql default collation type is not utf8_unicode_ci.

Do the following. Backup your data if you have to.
I had to drop the database and recreate it

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
```

Change mysql database collation to utf8_unicode_ci ( phpMyAdmin might come in handy here)
Finally, restore your migration.

```
rake db:migrate
```

Enjoy.